# Is $0\in \{ux+vy+wz=0\}\subseteq \mathbb C^6$ a quotient singularity?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, singularity-theory, orbifolds

I am trying to gain some intuition for telling when a variety has quotient singularities.

The example I am focusing on here is the affine variety $X$ which is cut out by the equation $ux+vy+wz=0$ in $\mathbb C^6=\mathbb C^3\times\mathbb C^3$, where $u,v,w$ are the first three coordinates and $x,y,z$ are the last three coordinates. In this case, the only singularity is $0\in X$.

> Is $0\in X$ a *quotient* singularity?

I know that for toric varieties, "$\mathbb Q$-factorial" and "(at worst) quotient singularities" are equivalent, but this variety $X$ is not toric. In general, I believe that it is true that "(at worst) quotient singularities" *implies* "$\mathbb Q$-factorial" (**right?**). This variety $X$ is factorial, so the contrapositive of the previous sentence does not apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that any punctured neighborhood $U \subset X$ of $0 \in X$ is simply connected, hence $(X,0)$ is not a quotient singularity.

Indeed, it is homotopy equivalent to an $S^1$-bundle over the flag variety
$$
F = \{ ux+vy+wz = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^2,
$$
such that the associated line bundle over $F$ has bidegree $(1,1)$. Since $F$ is simply connected, the exact sequence of the homotopy groups takes the form
$$
\dots \to \pi_2(F) \to \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(U) \to 0
$$
and the map $\mathbb{Z}^2 = \pi_2(F) \to \pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ in it is surjective, hence the claim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there an easy way to see why all such $U$'s being simply connected implies $0$ is not a quotient singularity?

Comment: If $X = Y/G$ then, assuming that $Y$ acts without complex reflections, and $0 \in X$ is an isolated singularity, then the quotient map from a punctured neighborhood of $0$ in $Y$ to a punctured neighborhood of $0$ in $X$ is a topological covering.

Comment: Sorry but I'm confused as to what the contradiction is (I'm not very familiar with these types of arguments). In this case, the quotient map $Y\to X$ is a covering on a punctured neighbourhood of $0$, but why does that mean we can't have $X=Y/G$?

Comment: You cannot have a covering of a simply connected space by a connected space; this is basic topology.

Comment: I guess I was just confused by the "punctured" part. So if $0$ was a quotient singularity, then we could write $U=Y/G$ for some neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, but then since $U\setminus 0$ is simply connected, $Y\setminus 0\to U\setminus 0$ is a homeomorphism, and this extends to a homeomorphism $Y\to U$, which yields the contradiction. Is this the idea?

Comment: There is even no need to extend the homeomorphism --- if $Y \setminus 0 \to U \setminus 0$ is one-to-one, the group is trivial, that's it.