# Factorial $+$ (at worst) quotient singularities $\implies$ smooth?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be a normal variety (irreducible) over a field $k$ which is algebraically closed and characteristic $0$. **Edit:** We can add the following assumption, which may help (?): $\mathscr O_X(X)^*=k^*$, i.e. the invertible global functions are constant.

My question is the following.

> If $X$ is factorial and has (at worst) quotient singularities, then does $X$ have to be smooth?

We can interpret *factorial* as $Cl(X)=Pic(X)$ or that all the local rings are UFDs, and we can interpret (at worst) *quotient singularities* as $X$ being étale locally of the form $V/G$ where $V$ is a smooth variety and $G$ is a finite group. Also, if it helps, we could just focus on the case where $X$ is affine.

I am trying to understand quotient singularities better. A few months ago, I asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782639/is-0-in-uxvywz-0-subseteq-mathbb-c6-a-quotient-singularity)  about a variety which is factorial but not smooth, and the answer said that it did not have (at worst) quotient singularities, so this would not be a counterexample to my question.

Comment: No. The standard $E_8$ singularity is a ufd.

Comment: @Mohan thanks for your comment! If you would like to post this as an answer, maybe with a reference for why it is a ufd, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^2+y^3+z^5)$ is an $E_8$ singularity and a ufd. Proofs can be found in P. Samuel's TIFR notes on ufd.