# Does $Spec(k[G/[P,P]])$ have worse than quotient singularities?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, algebraic-groups, singularity-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, let $G$ be a connected reductive linear algebraic group over $k$, and let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup of $G$. So we have the flag variety $G/P$. Suppose that this flag variety $G/P$ is not a toric variety, or equivalently that $G/P$ is not a product of projective spaces, or equivalently that the Cox ring of $G/P$ is not a polynomial ring over $k$.

I want to look at the spectrum of the Cox ring of $G/P$ in this case. As mentioned in Brion's paper "The total coordinate ring of a wonderful variety", the Cox ring of $G/P$ is equal to the coordinate ring of the quasi-affine variety $G/[P,P]$. Let $Y$ be the affine variety which is the spectrum of the coordinate ring of $G/[P,P]$. Again, by our supposition, $Y$ is not affine space.

> In this case, does $Y$ have worse than quotient singularities?

Clearly $Y$ is smooth if $G/P$ is a toric variety (in this case, $Y$ is affine space), which is why I want to rule out this case. My hunch is that, aside from this case that we have ruled out, $Y$ must have worse than quotient singularities.

In the question that I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4782639/is-0-in-uxvywz-0-subseteq-mathbb-c6-a-quotient-singularity), the answer shows that, in the case of $G=SL_3$ and $P=B$ the Borel subgroup, the corresponding $Y$ indeed has worse than quotient singularities (in this case, $[P,P]=U$ is the maximal unipotent subgroup). For clarity, $Y$ in this example is the spectrum of $k[u,v,w,x,y,z]/\langle ux+vy+wz\rangle$.

Comment: how does $k[G/[P,P])$ look like when $G/P:=SL(V)/P \cong \mathbb{G}(m,n)$ is the grassmannian?

Comment: @hm2020 good idea to start there. I'm not 100% certain, but I think that $Y$ is the affine cone over the grassmannian in this case. For example, for $G(2,4)$, we get the same variety as the one I mentioned above in that example. I am not familiar enough with Grassmannians to know about the singularities of their affine cones in general.

Comment: There is an inclusion $[P,P] \subseteq P$ and a surjective morphism $\pi: G/[P,P] \rightarrow G/P$. What type of a "fibration" is $\pi$ in the case of the grassmannian or projective space? For projective space there is the $\mathbb{G}_m$-principal fiber bundle $\rho: \mathbb{A}^{n+1}_k-\{(0)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$. Is $\rho$ related to $\pi$?

Comment: Note: The scheme $G/[P,P]$ is a regular quasi projective scheme of finite type over the base field.

Comment: @hm2020 thanks for your comments. I was thinking more about this last night after your first comment, and I was looking at how the approach in the answer to my other question (linked above) could apply to grassmannians. It seems like, if $G/P$ is a grassmannian, then $G/[P,P]\to G/P$ is a $\mathbb{G}_m$-bundle as well, so we could use the same homotopy argument. In this case $\pi_2(G/P)=\mathbb{Z}$ maps to $\pi_1(\mathbb{G}_m)=\mathbb{Z}$, and this map should be surjective, right?

Comment: The affinization map $G/[P,P] \rightarrow S:=Spec(k[G/[P,P])$ is an isomorphism iff $G/[P,P]$ is an affine scheme, and in this case $S$ is regular, hence for the scheme $S$ to be singular one must have $G/[P,P]$ non-affine. What is the reason for studying this ring for $G/[P,P]$?

Comment: @hm2020 indeed, in my situation $G/[P,P]$ is not affine. I am mainly interested in the spectrum of the Cox ring of this $G/P$, which as it turns out is the same as $Spec(k[G/[P,P]])$. As you say, this variety is singular, and I am wanting to say that the singularities are worse than quotient.